# Point apache2 to my own index.html folder?

Tags: apache2

In apache2 I am trying to get a folder that already has index files, video, picures (completely already built website) and put the folder in www and direct or point apache2 to one of the index files inside that folder so the web can run, the folder contains a website already configured with additional pages that are already configured but I need to point apache to that folder instead of the default index.html. Any one knows how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to change apache's DocumentRoot configuration.

1. check where configuration is.
   Generally, apache2 configuration file is located in /etc/apache2/ folder.

   vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

in that file, you can find out the location of "DocumentRoot" config

```
Include sites-enabled/
```

that indicates your configuration file is in "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/".

2.edit DocumentRoot config

```
vi /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

In that file, you can find the "DocumentRoot" like below

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

And, modify that as you want.

3.restart apache.

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, iam trying to solve another problem before i can test this, i'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I can't find root directoy but there is: # access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted